# GPU causes PC to go into endless reboot & no display (Radeon HD 7970)

Tags: drivers, graphics-card

I was experiencing a couple of blue screens on my (3 years old) PC so I decided to upgrade my drivers.
I updated my ATi Radeon 7970 driver to a certain version from ATi Catalyst which later turned out to be a version that causes problems with countless PCs (so much even there was rumor of a potential class action lawsuit).

Here's everything that happened:

- Started experiencing some crashes & blue screens
- Installed faulty ATi Catalyst version
- Computer stopped booting and started going into endless reboot mode without a display or BIOS
- Took out GPU, use onboard GPU
- Display recovered, windows no longer working
- Formatted hard drive, reinstalled Windows
- Windows now working
- Plug in GPU, PC goes back into no display & endless reboot mode

I just tried plugging the card in a different slot and it worked somewhat. I installed the latest driver using AMD Auto Detect, restarted, and booted up a game. In 2 minutes the game crashed, displayed a solid color, and I was forced to reboot. Upon reboot, the computer went into endless reboot mode again and I had to remove the GPU. I read that even some more recent ATi drivers are messing up the card. I used Guru3d Driver Uninstaller to uninstall the drivers, but I'm still unable to boot the PC with the card plugged in now.

Anyone know what could be up? I've had this PC for a few years without issues, and now after installing that driver my PC no longer seems to accept my GPU.

Comment: artifacts is an indication of a hardware issue not software.

Comment: Please do use curse words in comments.  I have no choice but to flag the comment now.

Comment: @Ramhound Misworded it, never really experienced artifacts. Just a solid color.

Comment: Your using the stable drivers or the beta drivers?  I still maintain the problems you indicate point to a hardware problem not software problem, you reinstalled Windows, and despite that you have the exact same problem you had before you did so.

Comment: @Ramhound I installed the 14.12 drivers. The odd part was that the GPU worked properly when I put it in my other slot, and then after installing the drivers & rebooting, it crashed after a few minutes and resulted in the same endless reboot. Now when I plug it in either port the PC reboots endlessly.

Comment: When a GPU exists without a driver it has limited capability.  When a driver exists the full functionality is accessible, if the GPU has failed in some capacity, it would explain this behavior.  A display device working without drivers and not working with drivers isn't all that unusual.

Comment: @Ramhound Alright, I'll take it the card has counted its days then. Thank you for the info.